# Problem with converting recursive code to iterative

Tags: recursion, code-review

I am trying to convert a snippet that uses recursion into one that uses iteration for drawing an L-tree, but my code produces duplicate points. How do I avoid generating them?

Recursive version:

```
ClearAll[tree,pts]
tree[A_,B_,1]:={
{A,B},
{(2A+B)/3,(2A+B)/3+RotationTransform[Pi/6][(B-A)/2]},
{(A+2B)/3,(A+2B)/3+RotationTransform[-Pi/6)][(B-A)/2]}
};
tree[A_,B_,n_]:=Join[
tree[A,(2A+B)/3,n-1],
tree[(2A+B)/3,(A+2B)/3,n-1],
tree[(A+2B)/3,B,n-1],
tree[(2A+B)/3,(2A+B)/3+RotationTransform[Pi/6][(B-A)/2],n-1],
tree[(A+2B)/3,(A+2B)/3+RotationTransform[-Pi/6)][(B-A)/2],n-1]];
pts=tree[{0.,0.},{0.,1.},2];//AbsoluteTiming
pts//Dimensions
Graphics@Line@pts
```

Iterative version:

```
ClearAll[tree,pts];
tree[{A_,B_}]:=
Block[{m=(2A+B)/3,n=(A+2B)/3,d=(B-A)/2},
{{A,m},{m,n},{n,B},{m,m+RotationTransform[Pi/6][d]},{n,n+RotationTransform[-(Pi/6)][d]}}
];
pts=Nest[Join@@tree/@#&,N@{{{0,0},{0,1}}},2];//Timing
pts//Dimensions
Graphics@Line@pts
```

[image]

Comment: The recursive version seems to have two extra ")" in the `RotationTransform` arguments

Comment: Your iterative code does not produce duplicate line segments.  I believe you need to keep duplicate points, so long as they define different line segments.